# Change Out of Stock Error Message in WooCommerce Cart

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, errors

I manage product inventory by manually entering the stock. When I have 2 in stock, but a guest adds 3 to their cart, WooCommerce shows the following error message:

[image]

I have located the code for this error message in the following file: 
woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart.php.

I made an attempt to copy this file into the following location in my child theme: mytheme/woocommerce/templates/includes/class-wc-cart.php. I then edited the message within the copy, and clicked save, thinking it would work. Instead, it broke my site (good think I'm using an FTP client, so I quickly reverted).

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a step I am missing in order to change this message? I thought simply copying it to my child theme would overwrite the original file as provided by WooCommerce.

Thank you,
R

Answer (score 1):

You have placed the new file in the incorrect folder location. The woocommerce folder in your child-theme should not contain 'templates'.
Use the following directory:
mytheme/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart.php

You can also edit this text by adding a filter
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23064185/woocommerce-changing-the-in-stock-text

Comment: Thanks! Realized you can only override template files, not class files. This is the code where the message is coming from:

   if ( ! $_product->has_enough_stock( $check_qty ) ) {
                    $error->add( 'out-of-stock', sprintf(__( 'Sorry, we do not have enough "%s" in stock to fulfill your order (%s in stock). Please edit your cart and try again. We apologise for any inconvenience caused.', 'woocommerce' ), $_product->get_title(), $_product->get_stock_quantity() ) );
                    return $error;
                }
How do I add a filter that changes this message?

Comment: Look at the link attached in my answer. Place it in your theme/child-themes function.php file

Comment: Thanks but that isn't the text that I am trying to change. I'm trying to change the error message above the cart, not the "out of stock" that appears next to the product in the catalog.